# how can i change the color of the image to solid black

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

[image]

I am trying to change the color of the word "MINNESOTA" to solid black using PS CS5 color replacement tool but I only get gray color. How can I change it to solid black?

Thanks.

Comment: Check your **Edit** > **Color Settings...** and make sure your colour profile is set up properly.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever possible let Photoshop do the heavy lifting, here is how:

1. Add a blank layer on top of the image you are working on, make a selection just to cover the area you want to affect, in this case "MINNESOTA"

[image]

2. Fill the selection with black, you are still on the new blank layer

[image]

3. Now, double click on this layer's icon in the layers palette to bring up the layer style window and change the position of the slider below Blend If as shown. You will lower the slider of the "Layer below" to roughly where I show it, but use your eyes as a guide. To split the slider to have a gentler transition, hold the Alt key down and click and drag the right side of the triangle.

[image]

4. You should now see the color of MINNESOTA converted to black. By the way, you can substitute any other color instead of black.

[image]

Here is the small layer stack for the record:

[image]